# Ansible - How to combine multiple disparate lists into to use in tasks loop

Tags: loops, merge, nested-lists, ansible-2.x

I have 3 lists like below

```
users:
  - "['user1', 'user2']"
permissions:
  - "[['Read'], ['Read', 'Write']]"
topics:
  - "[['Topic1', 'Topic2'], ['Topic3', 'Topic4', 'Topic5']]"
```

That I want to combine into a structure similar to this

```
  combined_lists:
    [
        {'user1', 'Read','Topic1'},
        {'user1', 'Read','Topic2'},
        {'user2', 'Read','Topic3'},
        {'user2', 'Read','Topic4'},
        {'user2', 'Read','Topic5'},
        {'user2', 'Write','Topic3'},
        {'user2', 'Write','Topic4'},
        {'user2', 'Write','Topic5'}
    ]
```

So that I can use it in a task like below

```
- name: Generate ACL command and run
  shell: |
    echo " kafka-acls --bootstrap-server broker1:9092 --command-config /kafka/configs/client.properties --add --allow-principal User:{{ item.0 }} --operation {{ item.1 }} --topic {{ item.2 }}"
  loop:
      "{{ combined_lists }}"
```

Can someone suggest what module should I use or look at to combine the lists which are lists of lists in the format that can be used to generate and execute the kafka-acl command ?  I tried to look at cartesian module but wasn't able to get it to work this way.

Appreciate any pointers regarding what modules to look at to achieve the outcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do with several set_facts loops:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    users: [ "user1", "user2" ]
    permissions: [ "Read", [ "Read", "Write"]]
    topics: [[ "Topic1", "Topic2"], ["Topic3", "Topic4", "Topic5"]]

  tasks:

    - name: SET_FACTS | Combine users and permissions
      vars:
        user: "{{ users[my_idx] }}"
        permission: "{% if item | type_debug == 'list' %}{{ item }}{% else %}{{ [item] }}{% endif %}"
      set_fact:
        combined_up: "{{ combined_up | default([]) + [[user] | product(permission) | list] }}"
      loop: "{{ permissions }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx

    - name: SET_FACTS | Combine users, permissions with topics
      vars:
        userpermission: "{{ combined_up[my_idx] }}"
        topic: "{% if item | type_debug == 'list' %}{{ item }}{% else %}{{ [item] }}{% endif %}"
      set_fact:
        combined_upt: "{{ combined_upt | default([]) + userpermission | product(topic) | list }}"
      loop: "{{ topics }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx

    - name: SET_FACTS | Create list of dictionary objects
      set_fact:
        combined_listd: "{{ combined_listd | default([]) + [{ 'user': item[0][0], 'permission': item[0][1], 'topic': item[1] }] }}"
      loop: "{{ combined_upt }}"

    - name: SET_FACTS | Create list of lists
      set_fact:
        combined_lists: "{{ combined_lists | default([]) + [[ item[0][0], item[0][1], item[1] ]] }}"
      loop: "{{ combined_upt }}"

    - name: DEBUG | list of dictionary objects
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.user }} - {{ item.permission }} - {{ item.topic }}"
      loop: "{{ combined_listd }}"

    - name: DEBUG | list of lists
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item[0] }} - {{ item[1] }} - {{ item[2] }}"
      loop: "{{ combined_lists }}"
```

and here the output:

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************

TASK [SET_FACTS | Combine users and permissions] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=Read)
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Read', 'Write'])

TASK [SET_FACTS | Combine users, permissions with topics] *****************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Topic1', 'Topic2'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Topic3', 'Topic4', 'Topic5'])

TASK [SET_FACTS | Create list of dictionary objects] **********************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[['user1', 'Read'], 'Topic1'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[['user1', 'Read'], 'Topic2'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[['user2', 'Read'], 'Topic3'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[['user2', 'Read'], 'Topic4'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[['user2', 'Read'], 'Topic5'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[['user2', 'Write'], 'Topic3'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[['user2', 'Write'], 'Topic4'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[['user2', 'Write'], 'Topic5'])

TASK [SET_FACTS | Create list of lists] ***********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[['user1', 'Read'], 'Topic1'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[['user1', 'Read'], 'Topic2'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[['user2', 'Read'], 'Topic3'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[['user2', 'Read'], 'Topic4'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[['user2', 'Read'], 'Topic5'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[['user2', 'Write'], 'Topic3'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[['user2', 'Write'], 'Topic4'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[['user2', 'Write'], 'Topic5'])

TASK [DEBUG | list of dictionary objects] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'user': 'user1', 'permission': 'Read', 'topic': 'Topic1'}) => {
    "msg": "user1 - Read - Topic1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'user': 'user1', 'permission': 'Read', 'topic': 'Topic2'}) => {
    "msg": "user1 - Read - Topic2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'user': 'user2', 'permission': 'Read', 'topic': 'Topic3'}) => {
    "msg": "user2 - Read - Topic3"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'user': 'user2', 'permission': 'Read', 'topic': 'Topic4'}) => {
    "msg": "user2 - Read - Topic4"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'user': 'user2', 'permission': 'Read', 'topic': 'Topic5'}) => {
    "msg": "user2 - Read - Topic5"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'user': 'user2', 'permission': 'Write', 'topic': 'Topic3'}) => {
    "msg": "user2 - Write - Topic3"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'user': 'user2', 'permission': 'Write', 'topic': 'Topic4'}) => {
    "msg": "user2 - Write - Topic4"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'user': 'user2', 'permission': 'Write', 'topic': 'Topic5'}) => {
    "msg": "user2 - Write - Topic5"
}

TASK [DEBUG | list of lists] **********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['user1', 'Read', 'Topic1']) => {
    "msg": "user1 - Read - Topic1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['user1', 'Read', 'Topic2']) => {
    "msg": "user1 - Read - Topic2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['user2', 'Read', 'Topic3']) => {
    "msg": "user2 - Read - Topic3"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['user2', 'Read', 'Topic4']) => {
    "msg": "user2 - Read - Topic4"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['user2', 'Read', 'Topic5']) => {
    "msg": "user2 - Read - Topic5"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['user2', 'Write', 'Topic3']) => {
    "msg": "user2 - Write - Topic3"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['user2', 'Write', 'Topic4']) => {
    "msg": "user2 - Write - Topic4"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['user2', 'Write', 'Topic5']) => {
    "msg": "user2 - Write - Topic5"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************
```